# Matching multiple path-components with `find`

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, find

Let's say I want to find all the `node_modules` folders in my Code directory:

```
find ~/Code -name 'node_modules' -type d
```

But what if I want to find all the `setup` folders, that themselves are inside `test` folders?

```
# nope
find ~/Code -name 'test/setup' -type d

# nope
find ~/Code -path 'test' -name 'setup' -type d
```

How do I perform a `find` search that matches **multiple path components** like this? i.e. find something named `foo/bar/baz.widget`, nested arbitrarily deep?

Comment: It seems that `-path` matches the whole path, try `'*test/setup'`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use a wildcard there:

```
$ find ~/Code -path '*/test/setup' -type d
```